# Editing My HTTP Call to Use Sockets (socket.io) to Receive Data via an Observable in my Angular 2 App

Tags: mongodb, angular, socket.io

Right now I have an http get call handling data coming from an api into my Angular 2 app. Now we're switching to using sockets via socket.io. I have been using an observable to get the data, and I know I can continue to do that while using socket.io sockets. But I'm having difficulty figuring out exactly what it should look like - i.e., how I need to edit my getByCategory function call to receive the data via a socket connection. This is what my getByCategory function currently looks like in my client-side Angular service:

```
   private _url: string = 'https://api.someurl';

    getByCategory() {
        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map((response:Response) => response.json())
            .catch(this._errorsHandler);
    }
    _errorsHandler(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error || "Server Error");
    }
```

And, on the server side, this is what my function export looks like in our mongoDB setup (already set up to use sockets via socket.io):

```
exports.getByCategory = function(req, res, next) {

    let skip, limit, stage, ioOnly = false;
    let role='office_default';
    if (_.isUndefined(req.params)) {
        stage = req.stage;
        skip = parseInt(req.skip) || 0;
        limit = parseInt(req.limit) || 0;
        role = req.role;
        ioOnly=true;
    }
    else {
        stage = req.params.stage;
        skip = parseInt(req.query.skip) || 0;
        limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 0;
        role = req.query.role;
    }
    console.log(role);
    Category[role].find({'services.workflow.status': stage}).skip(skip).limit(limit).exec(function(err, doc) {
        if (err) { if (!ioOnly) { return  next(err) } else { return res(err)}}
        else if(doc) ((!ioOnly) ? res.json(doc) : res(doc));
        else ((!ioOnly) ? res.sendStatus(204) : res(doc));
    });
};
```

How should I edit my getByCategory function to use socket.io instead of http in my service? Do I need an emit function coming from my api to act on in my Angular 2 service - or can I just adjust my current getByCategory function to use sockets within the existing observable instead?

I thought about editing the function to look something like this:

```
    getByStage() {
        this.socket.on('getByCategory')
            .map((response:Response) => response.json())
            .catch(this._errorsHandler);
    }
}
```

... but to do that I'd need the server function export to make it available via an "emit" or something similar, wouldn't I? Would it work if I did that? Am I missing something here?

Comment: AS far as I know, it is not possible.

You should map socket object to the socket connection and set up callbacks to work with them

Comment: So, you mean use "emit" and "on" and such, between server and client?

Comment: Yes, Buddy :)

An answer is given, please try that and let me know if that solves your problem or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to work with socket connection (like [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io)), you should depend on callbacks.

So, you should set up callback functions to work with them.

A demo is given here-

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

export class ChatService {
  private url = 'http://localhost:5000';  
  private socket;

  sendMessage(message){
    this.socket.emit('add-message', message);    
  }

  getMessages() {
    let observable = new Observable(observer => {
      this.socket = io(this.url);
      this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);    
      });
      return () => {
        this.socket.disconnect();
      };  
    })     
    return observable;
  }  
}
```

A complete tutorial of using Angular2 with socket.io is given **[here](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/socket.io-with-rxjs-in-angular-2.0)**.

Hope you have your answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that it's not really do-able the other way, Abrar. I will adjust both server and client to use "emit", "on", and callbacks.